# nd4j dataset change to zero when i use shuffle method

Tags: dl4j, nd4j

I am using DeepLearning4J and nd4j-cuda-10.2. all of the DataSet elements change to zero after I use the shuffle() method. I have traced the code and I think there is a problem with the registerAction() method.

```
DataSet data;
...
data.shuffle();
```

this is the data before shuffle:

```
===========INPUT===================
[[         0,         0,         0,  ...         0,         0,   16.0000], 
 [         0,         0,         0,  ...         0,    1.0000,   16.0000], 
 [    1.0000,         0,         0,  ...         0,    2.0000,   16.0000], 
  ..., 
 [    5.0000,   39.0000,         0,  ...   25.0000,   19.0000,   16.0000], 
 [    5.0000,   40.0000,         0,  ...   25.0000,   19.0000,   16.0000], 
 [    5.0000,   41.0000,         0,  ...   25.0000,   19.0000,   16.0000]]
=================OUTPUT==================
[[         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000], 
 [         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000], 
 [         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000], 
 [         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000], 
 [         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000], 
 [         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000], 
 [         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000], 
 [         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,    1.0000], 
 [         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000], 
 [         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,    1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,         0,    1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000], 
 [         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,    1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000], 
 [         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000], 
 [         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000], 
 [         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000], 
 [         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000], 
 [         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000], 
 [         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000], 
 [         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000], 
 [         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000], 
 [         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,   -1.0000,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,   -1.0000,         0]]
```

and after:

```
===========INPUT===================
[[         0,         0,         0,  ...         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,  ...         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,  ...         0,         0,         0], 
  ..., 
 [         0,         0,         0,  ...         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,  ...         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,  ...         0,         0,         0]]
=================OUTPUT==================
[[         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0], 
 [         0,         0,         0,         0,         0]]
```

in the registerAction() method operand.lengh is always Zero:

```
public void registerAction(CudaContext context, INDArray result, INDArray... operands) {
    if (result != null && !result.isEmpty()) {
        AllocationPoint point = this.allocator.getAllocationPoint(result);
        point.tickDeviceWrite();
        INDArray[] var5 = operands;
        int var6 = operands.length;

        for(int var7 = 0; var7 < var6; ++var7) {
            INDArray operand = var5[var7];
            if (operand != null && !operand.isEmpty()) {
                AllocationPoint pointOperand = this.allocator.getAllocationPoint(operand);
                pointOperand.tickDeviceRead();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: HI,  could you file an issue at https://gthub.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j/issues? Thanks!

Comment: is this the right address? I couldn't open it.

Comment: Sorry project is hosted on github. github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j/issues

Comment: I am having so much trouble using this library. even a simple example like IrisClassifieron on the repository won't run correctly. the neural network output is the same for all inputs. I can't figure out what am I missing.

Comment: could you be more concrete? If you can update your question, I'm happy to help. We have several getting started guides and examples at https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j-examples - if you can be more specific maybe I could solve your issue?

Comment: Hi @jahan: I commented on your github issue. Sorry for not seeing that.